# Go Tree structure in

Tags: go, tree

I have a little issue creating this kind of tree structure in go.

```
{
"uuid": "uuid1",
"label": "label1",
"children": [{
    "uuid": "uuid2",
    "label": "label2",
     "children": [{
        "uuid": "uuid3",
        "label": "label3",
            "children": [{
                "uuid": "uuid5",
                "label": "label5",
            },{
                "uuid": "uuid7",
                "label": "label7",
            }]
     },
     "uuid": "uuid4",
     "label": "label4",
            "children": [{
                "uuid": "uuid6",
                "label": "label6",
            }]
     }]
}]}
```

I tried it with maps, but I have a problem creating it. The map I came up with looked like this:

```
 Tree := make(map[string]map[string]map[string][]interface{})
```

The data would come from a database where every row looks something like this:

| uuid | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid5 | label5 | label3 | label2 | label1 |
| uuid7 | label7 | label3 | label2 | label1 |

I hope someone can help me with this, got some headache from that already.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: use `map[string]interface{}` the json decoder will automatically figure out if deals with maps or string or number. To use that variable apply type assertions to its value to figure out if you are dealing with string, map, or else.

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-speed-up-a-tree-structure-traversal-in-go-cd4bd6775520 hope this gives some idea

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Jason, your json tree structure is wrong. I would suggest using online [tools](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) for validating json's.

Apart from that, All you need to do here is to define a struct for your tree structure like below. Here is the working example on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qX84eLO-IdQ) with your json document.

```golang
type Node struct {
    UUID      string `json:"uuid"`
    Label     string `json:"label"`
    Childrens []Node `json:"children"`
}
```

We prefer using `structs` over `maps` as they are typesafe. Go being a strongly typed language, using structs is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The issue is that this does not work for me, as the data is not coming as json, it is coming from database as shown above. I wanted to use map because then I can check easily if a value already exists in the parent node and then add more children to that.

Comment: I believe that even in the database you might be saving the data as JsonOb. And once you unmarshall that in the structs it should be easy to process. Some more information about your specific problem might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well，I think you paste the text of tree structure is error。 I adjust it，like this：

```json
{
  "uuid": "uuid1",
  "label": "label1",
  "children": [
    {
      "uuid": "uuid2",
      "label": "label2",
      "children": [
        {
          "uuid": "uuid3",
          "label": "label3",
          "children": [
            {
              "uuid": "uuid4",
              "label": "label4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I offer to use Go Struct, not map。

Before two months，I found a nice [website](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/), which can help to convert to Go struct from JSON format struct。

Before Convert：

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    UUID     string `json:"uuid"`
    Label    string `json:"label"`
    Children []struct {
        UUID     string `json:"uuid"`
        Label    string `json:"label"`
        Children []struct {
            UUID     string `json:"uuid"`
            Label    string `json:"label"`
            Children []struct {
                UUID  string `json:"uuid"`
                Label string `json:"label"`
            } `json:"children"`
        } `json:"children"`
    } `json:"children"`
}
```